# How do I set PAM_RUSER when log in into ssh server?

Tags: ssh, pam

I'm trying to log all ssh connections with logger and notification by mail. I have followed this : [#179889](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful)

```
#!/bin/sh

sender="xxx"
recepient="xxx"

if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    host="`hostname`"
    subject="SSH Login: $PAM_USER@$host from $PAM_RUSER@$PAM_RHOST"
    # Message to send, e.g. the current environment variables.
    message="`env`"
    echo "$message" | mail -r "$sender" -s "$subject" "$recepient"
    # Logger
    logger -t ssh-wrapper $PAM_RHOST@$host from $PAM_RUSER@$PAM_RHOST
fi
```

The problem is that $PAM_**R**USER is empty.

How do I set this env variable ?

Answer (score 3):

Where did you get PAM_RUSER from?

PAM_RHOST is the remote host (i.e. source of the connection).
That is fairly straightforward: you need a (L)HOST (local) and a RHOST (remote) for a connection (yes, both can be 127.0.0.1 or ::1, or anything else, but you need it twice, because a connection here is point to point).

But PAM_RUSER is a different concept: if the RHOST provides a USER at all, that is the *local* user (i.e. the one on your LHOST) RHOST wants to authenticate as.

Tools like rlogin/rsh/rcp and co do have a concept of RUSER, since r*-tools rely on trusting hosts.

Something like SSH doesn't, because it doesn't trust the remote host, but the ability of to authenticate to a given account. 
In other words: with SSH, there is basically no RUSER, because SSH only cares about granting RHOST the ability to log in as LUSER on LHOST.

To put it differently: from a client perspective, unless you tell it to do otherwise, `ssh HOST` will use your local user name as the username to log in as - so RUSER == LUSER. If you choose to provide a different name, as in `ssh USER@HOST`, the SSH server only knows about whatever USER is provided to it, and no one talks what other values USER could have.

This is the general case - using e.g. Kerberos may change this, because there is then a notion of a reliably authenticated user (a principal) able to prove they are who they claim to be.

tl;dr: your care about USER/PAM_USER, because that is the account that would get compromised if access was incorrectly granted.

Edit: to account for updated info.

Looking at your use case, there might be a better way to get that kind of information/attribute - using public key authentication.
This then allows you to have logs like this one:

```
Mar 01 09:35:47 HOSTN sshd[60412]: Accepted publickey for USER from RHOST port 42088 ssh2: RSA xx:d6:09:xx:76:84:xx:7e:22:xx:af:a2:xx:b3:8b:xx
```

I am not completely sure how you would get an email sent, but you could consider one of the following options:

- use syslog to push this (and maybe other logs) to something central
- use some kind of log parser (for example logstash/beats) to monitor for this kind of event, and have that tool sent a notification. Not to cheerlead logstash, but aside from email, it would make it possible to get various other kinds of notifications, like slack/webhooks/etc.

It isn't, I admit, quite the same as your original solution (and requires you have some kind of human->key mapping - but that is generally a good thing to have anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the reply ;)
I know I can't trust the RUSER : from a client perspective, it's the local user and can be easily changed. It's just for information purpose : which coworker connect to the server (we share server's root account, and don't have the time to create a user for each coworker). So we can't have it set with ssh ?

Comment: Ho, I forgot : I try to get it from /etc/pam.d/sshd : 
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/login-notify.sh

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your use case. Obviously, I would have to mumble about having access to root being bad (I would strongly recommend an unprivileged account (e.g. teamuser, management, operator, whatever) with sudo rights instead). One other thing: you can also consider using an SSH CA (see e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu) in order to have a reasonable strong means of attribution